# how to fix column in data frame that was made into a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame in which I am manipulating the data around. When I used the aggregate function it gave me what I wanted but it placed it into a new column as a separate dataframe within the main dataframe. How can I make the "column dataframe" as a regular column?

Comment: You can try `unnest`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it with do.call(data.frame, df)